# Uploading Separate APKs for ARM-v7 and x86 to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publishing

I have made an Android game in Unity3D. I have published the game on Google Play.

The APK I'm currently serving is for both ARM-v7 and x86 native platforms. I want to upload a separate APK file for each to make them take up less storage space. The APK with both platforms is 27MB and the separate APKs are each around 19MB. The installed sizes are 56MB and 43MB, respectively. That's a significant difference.
The only information on this I have found relates to the APK tab in Google Play Developer Console, which is now deprecated.
Also, I have tried to upload separate APK files under the same version code and I got an error saying that two APKs can't have the same version code.
And when I tried to upload them under different version codes I got an error saying that the lower version APK is fully shadowed by the newer version.

How can I upload separate APK files for different native platforms?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Many x86 Android devices can use ARM libraries though binary code translation. So if you gave the x86 APK versionCode 1 and the ARM APK versionCode 2, and if all x86 devices you support can use the ARM libraries, then no device would get the x86 APK, because the ARM APK is newer. You might have better luck if you assign the higher versionCode to the x86 APK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new 'Manage Releases' system, you create a release and add both apks, with different version codes, to the same release. You must limit the native platform in each one with something like this in your build.gradle:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
            universalApk false
        }
```

The x86 version should have a higher version code, otherwise x86 devices will get the armv7a version since they are almost always compatible with that architecture as well.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to upload them under different version codes

Different version codes indicates different version but only in terms "newer" or "older".

> How can I upload separate APK files for different native platforms?

There's Multiple APK Support feature:

> By publishing your application with multiple APKs, you can:
>
> - Support different OpenGL texture compression formats with each APK.
> - Support different screen sizes and densities with each APK.
> - Support different device feature sets with each APK.
> - Support different platform versions with each APK.
> - **Support different CPU architectures with each APK (such as for ARM, x86, and MIPS, when your app uses the Android NDK).**

https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html